# JBoss 5.1.0GA: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null beanMetaData" and "java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to initialize bean container"

Tags: java, jboss, message, jboss5.x, ibm-mq

I am trying to deploy a ear file, which was originally written for Jboss 4.0.3 SP1.

The "upgrade" involved:

- use of javax.annotation.PostConstruct
- change activateConfig to activationConfig
- make sure the bean implements import javax.jms.MessageListener

I believe the following stack trace is triggered by a MDB (one and only) within a ejb file.

```
10:42:37,350 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfszip:/C:/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/my-service.ear/ state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error deploying my-service-ejb.jar: failed to initialize bean container
        at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3Deployer.deploy(Ejb3Deployer.java:196)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3Deployer.deploy(Ejb3Deployer.java:99)
        at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractVFSRealDeployer.java:45)
        at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:362)
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to initialize bean container
        at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.<init>(EJBContainer.java:253)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer.<init>(MessagingContainer.java:87)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MDB.<init>(MDB.java:63)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3AnnotationHandler.getMDB(Ejb3AnnotationHandler.java:336)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3AnnotationHandler.getContainers(Ejb3AnnotationHandler.java:215)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deployElement(Ejb3Deployment.java:718)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deployElement(Ejb3Deployment.java:669)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deployUrl(Ejb3Deployment.java:651)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deploy(Ejb3Deployment.java:614)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.create(Ejb3Deployment.java:491)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.deployers.Ejb3Deployer.deploy(Ejb3Deployer.java:182)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null beannMetaData
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.metadata.BeanInterceptorMetaDataBridge.setupMetaDataLists(BeanInterceptorMetaDataBridge.java:315)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.metadata.BeanInterceptorMetaDataBridge.initialise(BeanInterceptorMetaDataBridge.java:235)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.metadata.BeanInterceptorMetaDataBridge.<init>(BeanInterceptorMetaDataBridge.java:138)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.metadata.AdditiveBeanInterceptorMetaDataBridge.<init>(AdditiveBeanInterceptorMetaDataBridge.java:48)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.aop.BeanContainer.initialize(BeanContainer.java:194)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.<init>(EJBContainer.java:249)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.metadata.BeanInterceptorMetaDataBridge.setupMetaDataLists(BeanInterceptorMetaDataBridge.java:268)
        ... 44 more
```

Just wonder if anyone can suggest what to look at.

Comment: If you don't get any good answers, try serverfault instead.

Comment: Are you using annotations? Can you show the annotated MDB? Do you still have some deployment descriptors somewhere?

Comment: Can you show the full error trace?

Comment: Getting a similar error upgrading from JBoss 4 to 5, did you find anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be strange, but try to see if there are some libs missing for your project.

I was doing the same here, I tried to find some answer at google and nothing helps me.

Then when I try to look again my project and see that there are some libs missing. When I add its, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error on trying to deploy a ear , created by MAVEN.
The problem was simple: one *-ejb.jar was declared as a EAR module, and also as a dependency in other module. That lead to having 2 *-ear.jar in the EAR package, one in ROOT folder and other in lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this case when fixing some arquillian tests, this is how I ended up on this page :(. Seems this error is thrown when you have an Entity class that has inside an embedded class as a key:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Xyz")
public class Xyz  implements Serializable
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private XyzPK id;
...
}
```

My test deployment was missing class XyzPK and I was getting this strange "Null beannMetaData" error. Once I added it all is ok.